# How to read in string data and compute the sum of numbers from text file

Tags: bash

I have a text file that has a list of results from travel distance

**Traveldistance.txt**

```
12.1 meters
14.1 meters
```

Whenever I tried to compute the sum of the distance, the result will display this message

```
12.1
12.1
26.2
26.2
```

However, if I remove the word "meters" from the travel distance text file, it is able to compute perfectly, such as this

```
12.1
26.2
```

Is there any way to read in the string data and allow the distance to be computed perfectly, such as this

```
12.1 meters
26.2 meters
```

I have even tried while loop, but it did not even work. My codes are shown as below

```
#!/bin/bash

SUM=0;


for n in $(cat DistanceLog_TD01.txt)
do 
    SUM=$(echo "$SUM + $n" | bc); #Need help here
    echo $SUM;
        
done

echo $(date +"%m-%d-%Y %T") "Total distance:" $SUM "meters" >> totaldistance.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
<infile awk '{ print sum+=$1, $2 }'
```

add date&time to the output:

```
<infile awk '{ print sum+=$1, $2 }
END{ print date_time }' date_time="$(date +'%F %T')"
```

note that the *"date_time"* above would be the date&time before command *awk* execution. if you need the *date&time* when *awk* finished the processing, do:

```
<infile awk '{ print sum+=$1, $2 }' && echo "$(date +'%F %T')"
```

or if you have [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for the [`strftime()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-strftime_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029) function:

```
<infile awk '{ print sum+=$1, $2 } END{ print strftime("%F %T") }'
```

see [*awk* strftime() formatting here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-format-specifiers-2)

to add date&time and output in one line:

```
<infile awk '{ sum+=$1 } END{ print sum, $2, date_time }' date_time="$(date +'%F %T')"
```

again, you can use strftime() function for GNU awk to output date&time instead.